# No puedo implementar el local storage en mi programa que agrega y verificar codigos

Tags: javascript

he creado un programa que agrega códigos(numeros, Ejemplo: 001,002) para posteriormente verificarlos.
Cada vez que se agrega un numero, se almacena en una array .
El problema es que no he podido implementar el local storage en los códigos agregados para que cuando se recargue la pagina, no tenga que introducir de nuevo los códigos que ya había introducido anteriormente.

Este es el código de JS:

```js
//Funcion para agregar

let codigos = [];

const htmlAgregar = document.createElement('div');
htmlAgregar.classList.add('varHtmlAgregar')     


const formularioEnviar = document.querySelector('#formularioEnviar').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nuevoCodigo = document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value;
    
    if(codigos.includes(nuevoCodigo)){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Este codigo ya esta registrado</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }else if(nuevoCodigo == ''){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Ingresa un codigo</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
    }else{
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML =  `<p>Codigo Agregado Correctamente</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        codigos.push(nuevoCodigo);
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }
    
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código completo:

```js
//botones
const btnVerificar = document.querySelector('.verificar');
const btnAgregar = document.querySelector('.agregar');

//contenedores
const ctnVerificar = document.querySelector('.itfz');
const ctnAgregar = document.querySelector('.itfz2');



//funciones
listeners();
function listeners(){
    btnVerificar.addEventListener('click', abrirVerificar);
    btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', abrirAgregar);
}

function abrirVerificar(){
    ctnVerificar.classList.toggle('itfzVar');
    ctnAgregar.classList.remove('itfz2Var');
    btnVerificar.classList.toggle('verificarVar');
    btnAgregar.classList.remove('agregarVar')
}
function abrirAgregar(){
    ctnAgregar.classList.toggle('itfz2Var');
    ctnVerificar.classList.remove('itfzVar');
    btnAgregar.classList.toggle('agregarVar');
    btnVerificar.classList.remove('verificarVar')
}



//Funcion para agregar

let codigos = [];

const htmlAgregar = document.createElement('div');
htmlAgregar.classList.add('varHtmlAgregar')     


const formularioEnviar = document.querySelector('#formularioEnviar').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nuevoCodigo = document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value;
    
    if(codigos.includes(nuevoCodigo)){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Este codigo ya esta registrado</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }else if(nuevoCodigo == ''){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Ingresa un codigo</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
    }else{
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML =  `<p>Codigo Agregado Correctamente</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        codigos.push(nuevoCodigo);
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }
    
    
})




//Funcion para verificar
const formularioVerificar = document.querySelector('#formularioVerificar');
const btnuno = document.querySelector('#btnuno');
const btndos = document.querySelector('#btndos');
listeners2();
function listeners2(){
    formularioVerificar.addEventListener('submit', noReload);
}

function noReload(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let verificarCodigo = document.querySelector('#codigo_ingresado').value;
    let ctnVerificarCodigo = document.querySelector('#codigo_ingresado');

    document.querySelector('#codigo_ingresado').value = "";
    if(codigos.includes(verificarCodigo)){
        btnuno.style.background = '#00DB99';
        ctnVerificarCodigo.style.border = "1px solid #00DB99";
        setTimeout(function(){
            btnuno.style.background = '#C4C4C4';
            ctnVerificarCodigo.style.border = "1px solid #C4C4C4";
        }, 2000)
    }else if (verificarCodigo == ""){
        
        ctnVerificarCodigo.style.border = "1px solid #CC2528";

        const msmCtnVerificar = document.createElement('div');
        msmCtnVerificar.classList.add('varMsmCtnVerificar');

        const msmPVerificar = document.createElement('p');
        msmPVerificar.textContent = 'No ingresaste un codigo';

        msmCtnVerificar.appendChild(msmPVerificar);
        ctnVerificar.appendChild(msmCtnVerificar);

        setTimeout(function(){
            ctnVerificar.removeChild(msmCtnVerificar);
            ctnVerificarCodigo.style.border = "1px solid #C4C4C4";
        },2000)

    }else{
        btndos.style.background = "#CC2528";
        setTimeout(function(){
            btndos.style.background = "#C4C4C4";
        },2000)   
    }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.contenedor{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.contenedor__interfaz{
    width: 470px;
    height: 502px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}


/*Contenedor botones arriba*/
.btn{
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.ctn-btn{
    width: 202.55px;
    height: 65.55px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.verificar{
    background: #C4C4C4;
}
.verificarVar{
    background: #CC2528;
}
.agregar{
    background: #C4C4C4;
}
.agregarVar{
    background: #CC2528;
}




/*Contenedor itfz*/
.itfz{
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.itfzVar{
    display: flex;
}
.itfz p{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #CC2528;
    
}
.itfz input{
    width: 170px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz input::placeholder{
    color: #C2BABA;
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz input:focus{
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz input:focus::placeholder{
    color: #fff;
}
.itfz button{
    width: 93px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ctn-botones{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.resultadobotones{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #C4C4C4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.btnuno{
    margin-right: 87px;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
.btndos{
   
    transition: all 300ms;
}





/*Contenedor itfz 2*/
.itfz2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 380px;
    background: #CC2528;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.itfz2Var{
    display: flex;
    
}
.itfz2 p{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    
}
.itfz2 input{
    width: 170px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz2 input::placeholder{
    color: #C2BABA;
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz2 input:focus{
    text-align: center;
}
.itfz2 input:focus::placeholder{
    color: #fff;
}
.itfz2 button{
    width: 93px;
    height: 35px;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.itfz2 h6{
    padding-top: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    
}

/* variable */
.varHtmlAgregar{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
}
.varHtmlAgregar p{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.varMsmCtnVerificar{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}
.varMsmCtnVerificar p{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #CC2528;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistema para saber existencia en fotos de productos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1667a34085.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor__interfaz">
            
            <div class="btn">
                <div class="ctn-btn verificar">
                    <p>Verificar</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ctn-btn agregar">
                    <p>Agregar</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="itfz">
                <p>VERIFICAR</p>
                <form id="formularioVerificar">
                    <input type="text" name="" id="codigo_ingresado" placeholder="Ingresa el código">
                    <button id="boton">Buscar</button>
                </form>
                <div class="ctn-botones">
                    <div class="resultadobotones btnuno" id="btnuno"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></div>
                    <div class="resultadobotones btndos" id="btndos"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="itfz2">
                <p>AGREGAR</p>
                <div class="ctn-itfz">
                    <form id="formularioEnviar">
                        <input type="number" name="" id="codigo_agregado" placeholder="Ingresa el código" >
                        <button id="boton-agregar">Agregar </button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            

        </div>
        <div class="text-prevent" id="text-prevent"><p id="text-prevent2"></p></div>
       </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Puedes editar tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace Editar que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar lo que te falte. Una vez lo hayas hecho borra esta no-respuesta, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías leer antes de nada los numeros del localstorage y trabajar a partir de ellos

```
let codigos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("codigos") ?? "[]");

const htmlAgregar = document.createElement('div');
htmlAgregar.classList.add('varHtmlAgregar')     


const formularioEnviar = 
document.querySelector('#formularioEnviar').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nuevoCodigo = document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value;

    if(codigos.includes(nuevoCodigo)){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Este codigo ya esta registrado</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }else if(nuevoCodigo == ''){
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML = `<p>Ingresa un codigo</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
    }else{
        htmlAgregar.innerHTML =  `<p>Codigo Agregado Correctamente</p>`;
        ctnAgregar.appendChild(htmlAgregar);
        codigos.push(nuevoCodigo);
        localStorage.setItem("codigos", JSON.stringify(codigos));
        document.querySelector('#codigo_agregado').value = "";
    }


})
```

Así a medida que introduces un número lo agregas al localstorage

Comment: Listo, era algo tan simple y me estaba rompiendo la cabeza jajaja muchas gracias